# Does the ability score modifier go in the large box or the small oval?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-sheets

When filling in the ability scores section of the standard character sheet as used in the D&D 5e Player's Handbook, I've seen a lot of people put each ability score in the large box, and the corresponding ability score *modifier* in the small oval below it. This makes sense to some because that's the order you're writing it from top to bottom.

However, it seems more practical to put the ability score modifier in the large box, since that's almost always the number you need to look at, and the ability score in the small oval.

Is there any official ruling on this, or other evidence to suggest which approach (if either) is official, standard, or more correct?

Comment: The bigger "circle" is actually more of a rectangle (maybe with rounded/tapered corners)...

Comment: I don't see how this is opinion based. He is asking for the ruling on it. If there is no ruling, then the answer is "there is no ruling and it doesn't actually matter". None of these cases is opinion-based. It's similar to how "up to the DM" is not motive for closing.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Modifier in the big circle

This is the way the [character sheets for the starter set](http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/StarterSet_Charactersv2.pdf) are filled out. Also makes the more frequently used modifier bigger and easier to read, so I would also recommend it.

Answer (score 25):

## No official ruling, so it's down to personal preference.

Although [Szega has mentioned](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134307/does-the-ability-score-modifier-go-in-the-big-or-little-circle/134309#134309) that in the Starter Set the modifier goes into the big space, no actual ruling about is is made, according to my knowledge, in any published book or from Crawford. As mentioned in [a comment by Chris Hep](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134307/does-the-ability-score-modifier-go-in-the-big-or-little-circle/134323#comment335961_134309), D&D Beyond allows either. Roll20 uses the modifier in the big space, at least in the sheets my online table has been using. Pre-gens for other campaigns also use the modifier in the big circle, as a note.

The placement in the big circle has more advantages than drawbacks - the modifier is the number you are usually interested in, not the actual value (exception for some mechanics that reduce your attribute). But, ultimately, the player chooses where he wants to write it.

Comment: To reinforce that it's down to personal preference - dndbeyond allows the user to swap them. Character sheets are a guide to help you track your character - they are not actually part of the rule-set.

Answer (score 4):

Both are considered acceptable; in my experience it is more common to see your "Score" on top and your "Modifier" on the bottom, but Wizards of the Coast seems to  be favoring Modifier on top in 5th. I have seen third party modules that use "Score" on top and D&D Beyond allows for both, so it really is preference in how you want it displayed.

Comment: "some of" - do you have any example of premade character that has modifier on the bottom?

Comment: @Mołot  after going over my sheets, only from non WotC sources, they seem to of adopted the <opinion>backwards</opinion> method.

Comment: So both official and 3rd party premade characters use method you consider backwards?

Comment: no, @Mołot most of my 3rd party use "ScoreTop", WotC seems to be mostly using "Mod Top"