# What are these circled numbers under the Modifier Numbers?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, character-sheets

What is the circled number in the modifier section? How do you use it?[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange! The (dungeons-and-dragons) tag is for those questions that are about the entire D&D franchise, as opposed to about a specific edition. Please tag this with which edition you're playing.

Comment: Your last question was about 5th edition, and that looks like a 5e character sheet. Is it safe to say this is about the same?

Comment: Although this particular thing is valid all the way back to 3.0....

Comment: Related 5e question: [Does the ability score modifier go in the large box or the small oval?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134307/does-the-ability-score-modifier-go-in-the-large-box-or-the-small-oval)

Comment: This does look like a photo of the D&D 5e sheet - either one of the pregens that come with the Starter Set or a version someone printed themselves - but I'll wait for OP to weigh in and confirm that themselves so as to avoid guessing.

Comment: I put down 5e earlier because it was just a guess(i think it is 5e but i have no idea what the differences are) i thought i read some where it was a 5e... Sorry for the confusion.. I am wondering about what the number in the smaller oval section. Amd is the bigger, sqaured, number the modifier(my party has been using the bigger number as the modifier)

Comment: You don’t need to know the differences (they’re sometimes major), but you do need to know which one you’re playing in order to ask questions about it here. Is this from your Starter Set / Lost Mine of Phandelver box? If so, remember to say that in the question. That’s enough for us to know that’s 5e.

Comment: @mattdm Superficially, yes. But what you do with it has different details in each. I expect a 5e answer would mention the level-up adjustment and how that affects things, in order to anchor them to the modifier to show why anyone would care about them.